# Android layout with different items on landscape and on portrait

Tags: android, landscape, screen-orientation, portrait

I have main.xml in res/layout-land and in res/layout. There's a grid of 12 icons, 3 by 4 (width, height, respectively). If the user rotates to landscape, I want to display them with a ViewPager of 3 by 2, and 3 by 2 in two pages. So in the res/layout there's a grid of 12 items and in the res/layout-land there's a ViewPager, to which I need to give a PagerAdapter.

My question is: under the assumption I'm working with configChanges="orientation", how do I do that? Or more specifically, Where for example do I give the ViewPager its PagerAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(display.getOrientation() == 0)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_portrait);
    else
        setContentView(R.layout.main_landscape); //getOrientation gives 1 here
}
```

Comment: You would give the View pager in the above if/else statement.

Comment: Although I would suggest instead creating a `res/values-land/integer.xml` and `res/values-port/integer.xml` which would allow you specify `<integer>`s in the same layout xml rather than possibly duplicating functionality by creating two layout files.

Comment: So what you're saying is there isn't a way to do it with res/layout-land and res/layout?

Comment: Do we conclude is it the only way to do it?

It seems very confusing and for me it's hard to believe there's no way to specify completely different widgets for each layout folder. If it's the case, then the layout folders just serve for re-positioning widgets, not to replace a different set of items in screen.

Not trying to go against your answer, but I really want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You could make two layout files and at the beginning of your onCreate() (just after super.onCreate(bundle) line), put an if/else statement around this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to look like this:

```
if(orientation==LANDSCAPE)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_landscape);
else
    setContentView(R.layout.main_portrait);
```

and from then on, wherever your java code would be different, just wrap it in the same condition. It's a little long-winded if your java code is very dependent on being in portrait, but I can't think of a better solution atm.

Also, depending on your application and it's functionality, you may need to recreate the activity on orientation change. But again, it may not be necessary.

I hope this helps